# Combination of Moq and Equals() crashing the MS Testing framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have what I think should be a very simple test case, but every time I run it QTAgent32 dies.  Running the test case in Debug mode shows a `System.StackOverflowException` being thrown in 'Unknown Module'.  I've narrowed it down to the most basic implementation that exhibits this behavior (.NET 4 and VS 2010 Ultimate):

```
[TestClass]
public class StackOverflow
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateStackOverflow()
    {
        var mockMyType1 = new Mock<MyType>();
        mockMyType1.Setup(m => m.Equals(mockMyType1.Object)).Returns(true);

        var mockMyType2 = new Mock<MyType>();

        // Real test is for a filtering routine and the Assert is using
        // Contains(), but it uses Equals() internally so it has the same problem
        Assert.IsTrue(mockMyType1.Object.Equals(mockMyType1.Object)); // returns true
        Assert.IsFalse(mockMyType1.Object.Equals(mockMyType2.Object)); // explodes
    }
}

public class MyType
{
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return false;  // Not the real implementation but irrelevant to this issue
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something important about closures or maybe Moq, but it seems like this should work.  Things I have tried, attempting to understand the issue, but have only confused me more:

- I tried replacing the Equals() setup with `mockMyType.Setup(m => m.Equals(m)).Returns(true);` but that causes Moq to throw an NotSupportedException
- If I make CallBase true instead of setting up Equals(), everything works
- Finally, if the MyType class doesn't override Equals(), everything works.

Can anyone point me in the direction of what might be happening?  I'm completely at a loss.

Edit: I believe I have a couple of options for making this work (including Lanorkin's response below), but I'd really like to know why this is happening.  Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in Moq or Visual Studio that I should be submitting?

Update: I ended up going with a version of Denys solution below and filing a [bug report to Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=362).  My setup now looks like:

```
mockMyType1.Setup(m => m.Equals(It.Is<MyType>(x => ReferenceEquals(x, mockMyType1.Object)))).Returns(true);
```

Comment: You're asserting mock against mock. Why should you do this?

Comment: I need to check that the list of items was filtered appropriately.  The real code actually uses results.Contains(), but since it appears to use Equals() internally, it results in the same thing.  Added comment to code indicating as much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question disturbs me since yesterday and finally I found the answer. You have to use a function in your setup method and it should assert against real equality of the mock objects. What I mean is `ReferenceEquals`. So I modified your `GetMockMyTypes` code. Sure it can't be used as a reference but intent is clear so far:

```
public static class MyTypeHelper
{
   public static IList<MyType> GetMockMyTypes()
   {
      var myTypes = new List<MyType>();

      var myMock1 = new Mock<MyType>().Object;
      Mock.Get(myMock1)
          .Setup(m => m.Equals(It.Is<MyType>(x => ReferenceEquals(x, myMock1))))
          .Returns(true);
      Mock.Get(myMock1).Setup(m => m.IsActive).Returns(false);
      myTypes.Add(myMock1);

      var myMock2 = new Mock<MyType>().Object;
      Mock.Get(myMock2)
          .Setup(m => m.Equals(It.Is<MyType>(x => ReferenceEquals(x, myMock2))))
          .Returns(true);
      Mock.Get(myMock2).Setup(m => m.IsActive).Returns(true);
      myTypes.Add(myMock2);

      return myTypes;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is more complex than I thought would be necessary, but it does seem to work and will function regardless of the type passed in.  Still not sure why the original doesn't work but hopefully I'll get something useful from the bug report. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, mocking Equals(object) make it fail (use Reflector/dotPeek to see more):

[image: MOQ StackOverflow]

Good news - it's easy to workaround. Just add Equals overload to `MyType` class, thus mocking `Equals(MyType)` instead of `Equals(object)`:

```
    public virtual bool Equals(MyType obj)
    {
        return Equals((object)obj);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately I'm not allowed to install either of those products here at work.  It does look like this will indeed work, but do you have any insight as to why this is the case?  Based on what you see, is this a bug in Moq?  I'd rather not modify my domain objects to work around a testing bug.

Comment: For me it looks like moq bug - you may try reporting it to them.

Comment: This is a reasonable solution for this test but doesn't work in all cases since my particular test will call Equals(MyType) but other methods might call Equals(object) which won't die but also won't return true.  I think I'm going to use some version of @denys solution.  I did submit a [bug report to Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/issues/detail?id=362), but haven't heard anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you do:

```
mockMyType.Setup(m => m.Equals(mockMyType.Object)).Returns(true);
```

which only mocks against parameter of that same object. If you use any other parameter it will not get matched.

Please try to do this instead:

```
mockMyType.Setup(m => m.Equals(It.IsAny<MyType>())).Returns(true);
```

However, you should get a different exception about unexpected method call.

Comment: While that change does prevent the explosions, that forces Equals() to return true for any MyType object which won't make the overall test function.  For instance, the assertion above would always fail regardless of the contents of results.

Comment: Well I don't know what you're trying to test there, but it's up to you what to return on which mock objects. My point there was that in your code you didn't match the correct method calls.

Comment: I think I'm confused because the only method to override is Equals(object); there isn't another method to mock.  If I change explicitly cast (object)mockMyType in both the setup and execution of Equals() it still fails even though now they are all objects.  Sorry if I'm totally missing the point.

Comment: Ok, tried to edit but ran out of time.  Here is my line of thought and you can tell me where I'm missing the point.  I'm not using MockBehavior.Strict so unexpected method calls should just return the default for the return type.  Therefore, the first Assert (in this version) should and does pass because I'm passing in the exact same object (as you said).  The second assert should pass because Equals() should just return the default for bool, which is false.  It sounds like you also agree that it is a bug.